# Dynamic time sleep until new minute starts with HH:MM:01 second

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, minute

I have a python code which usually runs within 20 to 48 seconds.

Currently I am using `time.sleep(10)` after the code + with while true & Try to run the same code after 10 second.

My objective is to use `time.sleep(dynamic)` so that multiple iteration of my code in same time minute stamp(within same minute)can be stopped to remove duplication of data values.

For example :

```
##Let say Code runs at 12:30:01 pm

while True:
    try:
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        start = '11:45:01'
        end = '18:02:00'
        if current_time > start and current_time < end:while True:
            Import Code1  ## run first program file
            Import Code1  ## run second program file
            Time.sleep(3)
        else:
            print("out of time")
            time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(3)
        continue
    continue
```

Now if code finishes at 12:30:50 pm then `time.sleep(remianing second)` should be = `10.`
if code finishes at 12:30:57 pm then `time.sleep(remianing second)` should be = `3.`
and if code finishes at 12:30:40 pm then `time.sleep(remianing second)` should be = `20.`
and so on…

Restart next iteration at 12:31:01 second (or after).

Comment: Off-topic: Note that `import`ing a module to execute it will only work once.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You already know how to get the current time using `datetime.now()`. You can get the current second from that and then sleep for `60-second` seconds.

Comment: @martineau..You saved me..Changed from `'import myfile'` to `os.system('myfile.py')` Hoping this is the best option to ensure while loop keeps running and if something fails ,it will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sleep the necessary amount of remaining time up to a minute by marking the time when the work starts and finishes, e.g.

```
import time
import random


while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,5))  # do some work
    worked_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("worked for", worked_time)
    wait_to_align = 60.0 - worked_time % 60.0
    print(f"sleep {wait_to_align} to align to a minute")
    time.sleep(wait_to_align)
```

produces

```
worked for 3.002328634262085
sleep 56.997671365737915 to align to a minute
worked for 5.003056764602661
sleep 54.99694323539734 to align to a minute
...
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wish for.Thank you so much.